# Why does visual studio 2017 give error "unable to attach to the process. An operation is not legal in the current state"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to attach to an instance of chrome running a react page, using node as a server. I want to attach to the chrome process to debug the front end. I've tried opening chrome using <kbd>win run</kbd> `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222` per instructions in [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/nodejs/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx). I then run the app with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> start without debugging and choose Debug->attach to the process. First I got the error

> Unable to attach to the process. An operation is not legal in the current state

Now I get

> Unable to attach to the process. The operation was cancelled.

or

> Unable to attach to the process. The operation timed out.

This is not an ASP page and all the similar errors I found are related to asp.
Closing chrome, and disabling javascript didn't work. Attaching as native code allows me to attach but I can't hit breakpoints.

Comment: Are you using VS2017 15.6? This issue has been reported and it's been fixed in 15.6, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25008/chrome-debugging-crashes-vs-with-an-operation-is-n.html

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT I'm on VS 2017 15.6.4

Comment: It is not very clear what kind of code you want to debug.  Well, not native, hard to imagine that disabling JS debugging is going to be joyful.  Browsers are like cookies, if Chrome doesn't taste good then try another brand.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I attached to firefox but it's strange that the same thing happened on every Virtual Machine on different web sites, so there must be something I did wrong. Strangely VS code did the same thing with chrome and I suspected it was an add on that was syncing to all my signed in chromes on the VM's but disabling didn't fix.

Comment: @user5389726598465 Have you tried: Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General and turn off the setting for Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE) ?

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT yes, didn't work.